# Implementing a ReaderWriter class based upon separate stateful Reader and Writer bases

Tags: c++, inheritance

Suppose I have two classes...

We can call the first `FooReader` and it looks something like this:

```
class FooReader {
public:
    FooReader(const Foo* const foo)
    : m_foo(foo) {

    }

    FooData readFooDataAndAdvance() {
        // the point here is that the algorithm is stateful
        // and relies upon the m_offset member
        return m_foo[m_offset++];
    }

private:
    const Foo* const m_foo;
    size_t m_offset = 0; // used in readFooDataAndAdvance
};
```

We can call the second `FooWriter` and it looks something like this:

```
class FooWriter {
public:
    FooWriter(Foo* const foo)
    : m_foo(foo) {

    }

    void writeFooDataAndAdvance(const FooData& foodata) {
        // the point here is that the algorithm is stateful
        // and relies upon the m_offset member
        m_foo[m_offset++] = foodata;
    }

private:
    Foo* const m_foo;
    size_t m_offset = 0;
};
```

These both work wonderfully and do their job as intended. Now suppose I want to create a `FooReaderWriter` class. Note that the

I naturally want to say that this new class "is a" `FooReader` and "is a" `FooWriter`; the interface is simply the amalgamation of the two classes and the semantics remain the same. I don't want to reimplement perfectly good member functions.

One could model this relationship using inheritance like so:

```
class FooReaderWriter : public FooReader, public FooWriter { };
```

This is nice because I get the shared interface, I get the implementation and I nicely model the relationship between the classes. However there are problems:

- The `Foo*` member is duplicated in the base classes. This is a waste of memory.
- The `m_offset` member is separate for each base type, but they need to share it (i.e. calling either `readFooDataAndAdvance` and `writeFooDataAndAdvance` should advance the same `m_offset` member).

I can't use the PIMPL pattern and store `m_foo` and `m_offset` in there, because I'd lose the const-ness of the `m_foo` pointer in the base `FooReader` class.

Is there anything else I can do to resolve these issues, without reimplementing the functionality contained within those classes?

Comment: Regarding the `m_offset` member, If you look at [the standard C++ stream classes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io) they *do* use different read and write offsets. This makes it easy to read and write step-wise (i.e. you read one value, and then overwrite that value without any seeking).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg that's a good point, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems ready made for the mixin pattern. We have our most base class which just declares the members:

```
template <class T>
class members {
public:
    members(T* f) : m_foo(f) { }
protected:
    T* const m_foo;
    size_t m_offset = 0;
};
```

and then we write some wrappers around it to add reading:

```
template <class T>
struct reader : T {
    using T::T;

    Foo readAndAdvance() {
        return this->m_foo[this->m_offset++];
    };
};
```

and writing:

```
template <class T>
struct writer : T {
    using T::T;

    void writeAndAdvance(Foo const& f) {
        this->m_foo[this->m_offset++] = f;
    }
};
```

and then you just use those as appropriate:

```
using FooReader = reader<members<Foo const>>;
using FooWriter = writer<members<Foo>>;
using FooReaderWriter = writer<reader<members<Foo>>>;
```

Comment: Mmm, I'd forgotten about mixins! Seems like exactly what I need. However this does lose the const-ness of the Foo pointer in the reader case, but this could be solved by making `members` a template and passing `const Foo` as T in the reader case and `Foo` in the writer case. Thank you very much.

Comment: @OMGtechy Do you need that `const`ness though? It's private to the class, and is only exposed via the `reader` which isn't returning a modifiable reference. It should be transparent to the end user.

Comment: it's more a matter of being able to pass a const pointer into the ctor of the reader class

Comment: @OMGtechy That makes sense. Edited that into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

CRTP.

```
template<class Storage>
class FooReaderImpl {
public:
  FooData readFooDataAndAdvance() {
    // the point here is that the algorithm is stateful
    // and relies upon the m_offset member
    return get_storage()->m_foo[get_storage()->m_offset++];
  }
private:
  Storage const* get_storage() const { return static_cast<Storage const*>(this); }
  Storage * get_storage() { return static_cast<Storage*>(this); }
};
template<class Storage>
class FooWriterImpl {
public:
  void writeFooDataAndAdvance(const FooData& foodata) {
    // the point here is that the algorithm is stateful
    // and relies upon the m_offset member
    get_storage()->m_foo[get_storage()->m_offset++] = foodata;
  }
private:
  Storage const* get_storage() const { return static_cast<Storage const*>(this); }
  Storage * get_storage() { return static_cast<Storage*>(this); }
};

template<class T>
struct storage_with_offset {
  T* m_foo = nullptr;
  std::size_t m_offset = 0;
};
struct FooReader:
  FooReaderImpl<FooReader>,
  storage_with_offset<const Foo>
{
  FooReader(Foo const* p):
    storage_with_offset<const Foo>{p}
  {}
};
struct FooWriter:
  FooWriterImpl<FooWriter>,
  storage_with_offset<Foo>
{
  FooWriter(Foo* p):
    storage_with_offset<Foo>{p}
  {}
};
struct FooReaderWriter:
  FooWriterImpl<FooReaderWriter>,
  FooReaderImpl<FooReaderWriter>,
  storage_with_offset<Foo>
{
  FooReaderWriter(Foo const* p):
    storage_with_offset<Foo>{p}
  {}
};
```

If you need an abstract interface for runtime polymorphism, inherit `FooReaderImpl` and `FooWriterImpl` from them.

Now, `FooReaderWriter` obeys the ducktype contract of `FooReader` and `FooWriter`.  So if you use type erasure instead of inheritance, it will qualify for either (at point of use).

I'd be tempted to change them to

```
using FooReader = std::function<FooData()>;
using FooWriter = std::function<void(FooData const&)>;
```

and then implement a multi-signature `std::function` for `FooReaderWriter`.  But I'm strange and a bit unhinged that way.